# Tomcat webapp can't find file in WebContent?

Tags: file, jsp, web-applications, navigation, tomcat6

I've lots of jsp files in the WebContent folder and also a user folder there.
When the user navigates to a a file in the user folder and then tries to navigate to a file in the WebContent folder again the app crashes.

I've tried getRealPath() but no good.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "The app crashes" doesn't really give much to help with. What exactly happens? Do you get any errors/exceptions on screen or in the logs? Please share them. They contain the answer.

Comment: Sorry not that clear aight. It's looking for the the file in the WebContent folder within the user folder. (e.g.) /testapp/user/details instead of /testapp/details. Hope that's a bit more clear. cheers for the response.